# Angular - Access Enums from view

Tags: angularjs, enums, global-variables, constants, global

I have some server side enums that I'm sending down to an angular application.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to access the enums for this sort of behavior:

```
<select ng-options="type.name as type.value for type in Enums.TYPES" />
```

I've tried several things to get this working:

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('Enums', {myEnumObject})

var Enums = {myEnumObject};

$window.Enums = {myEnumObject};
```

obviously, none of these ways make the object accessible from the view.  I've also tried using services to return the object, but that doesn't make it accessible from the view.

My problem here is that I know it can be done from the scopes, using one of these:

```
$rootScope.Enums = {myEnumObject};
OR
$scope.Enums = {myEnumObject};
```

My concern with this is that this seems unsustainable.  Using a scope seems like bad practice since every child scope created will be polluted with this data.

I could also do it by assigning the enums to a controller, but then that seems like it's kind of defeating the purpose of having these global objects.  In reality, they ARE constants that never change.

It seems like I must be missing something here.  Can somebody point me in the right direction for maintaining sustainability for this code, as well as handling it in an "angular" way.  Thanks.

Comment: With angular, the point of the scope is to say, "For the view that is in context with this scope, I want to make available this set of data". So I don't see anything wrong with assigning the enum to the relevant scope at the relevant time. What makes that unsustainable? If you are using the enums in your view, then they aren't polluting that scope, because they need to be there.

Comment: @MattWay They might not be polluting the scope that I'm currently in, but any child scopes that are created off of that ARE polluted (since they are created off the parent)

Comment: @MattWay As for sustainability, I think it's more of a duplication of code thing.  If I need Enums.Types, it seems unnecessary to be creating a $scope.Enums variable when the variable already exists at the global level.  Just from a low level standpoint, it's taking up more stack space and all that jazz (though in reality, it probably doesn't have that big an impact)

Comment: Depending on how you are using your enum in the view, if you took a directive centric method, and wrapped your use of enum (and view) in a directive with an isolate scope, you could bundle everything together.

Comment: @MattWay So you're suggesting something like an "enum select box" directive that takes an enum type and allows selection for that particular enum?  That would also allow me to limit child scopes created off that directive.  It still seems like there should be some better way to expose global constants in an angular view, but I think this is a better solution than anything I've though of.  Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid attaching the constant or service enum to every scope you need, is to take a directive centric design to your application. As directives can have isolate scopes, you can bundle your views/controller and *scope bindings* together in a nice reusable package. For example:

```
.directive('SomeEnumThing', function(Enums){
    return {
        scope: {}, // don't forget to set an isolate scope on the directive
        templateUrl: 'sometpl.html',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

            // bind the enums to your directive's scope
            scope.enums = Enums;
        }
    };
});
```

The only downsides to this method are the extra verbosity in writing a directive (but ultimately more reusable), and the added requirement of setting up any other necessary bindings with outside objects (as you are now outside the general scope hierarchy).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
angular.module('myModule').constant('Enums', {myEnumObject})
```

Then in any scope that you want to use it, you can

```
$scope.Enums = Enums;
```

This is not very polluting, only a scope that requires it will have it set.

Global constants can be put on the `$rootScope`, and this can be seen as polluting. But if this is something that you do need all throughout your app in various directives, it's not such a big deal (IMO). There's no correct answer to this question.

Comment: "Only a scope that requires it will have it set"  This isn't necessarily true, since any scope that inherits from that scope will also have it.